# Microsoft OAuth2.0 admin consent API returns error AADSTS90027 and can't get token

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am providing an application that performs OAuth 2.0 authentication using Microsoft IDs, but the other day an error suddenly occurred and the authentication could not be performed, and the situation is still continuing.
It was working fine until then.

We are using the admin_consent API to get tokens, as shown in the following URL.
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/graph/auth-v2-service

Now, before going to the Microsoft login screen, we are redirected to a URL with parameters indicating an error.
The parameters look like the following:

```
?error=invalid_request&error_description=AADSTS90027%3a+We+are+unable+to+issue+tokens+from+this+API+version+on+the+MSA+tenant.+Please+contact+the+application+vendor+as+they+need+to+use+version+2.0+of+the+protocol+to+support+this.%0d%0aTrace+ID%3a+60c3dfca-739d-439a-94e3-05345df4ea00%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+907818ee-d2f2-444e-acc8-745c102251fa%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2021-04-26+05%3a33%3a02Z&admin_consent=True&state=80ffc4c9-e395-4d64-8b34-41531015a780#
```

We are using this endpoint URL:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent
```

I don't see how this could be wrong.

I have searched for this error message but am having trouble finding an effective solution. Is there anything I can do to improve the situation?

Comment: You need to use the v2.0 administrator consent url.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-admin-consent#request-the-permissions-from-a-directory-admin

Comment: @CarlZhao Thanks! It seems to resolve my problem.
By the way, do you know why we started getting this error...? The URL ( https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent ) had worked well until last week.

Comment: This is related to the type of account you are using. Are you using a personal account?

Comment: I'm using a personal account to register my application in Azure Portal. I didn't have any problems before, but I wonder if the specification had suddenly changed.

Comment: I think this may be the reason for the application, you can try to change the application manifest: https://i.stack.imgur.com/99thT.png

Comment: `AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount`

Comment: In several years I have not changed the manifest. "signInAudience" property is set to `AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount`